# EF Core 3 DbQuery equivalent functionality

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

In ef core 2.2 I have used DbQuery to map raw sql results to object as following:

```
public partial class AppDbContext{
    public DbQuery<SimpleQueryModel> SimpleQM {get;set;}
}
```

and then

```
var result=_dbContext.SimpleQM.FromSql(sqlString,params);
```

this wouldn't create any extra table and working just fine.
In ef core 3.1 DbQuery is obsolete and telling me to use keyless DbSet instead.
I have configured it as following:

```
public partial class AppDbContext{
    public DbSet<SimpleQueryModel> SimpleQM {get;set;}
}
```

and in ModelCreating

```
builder.Entity<SimpleQueryModel>().HasNoKey();
```

but this will create a new table in new DB migration and if I tell ef to Ignore this entity as following

```
builder.Entity<SimpleQueryModel>().HasNoKey().Ignore();
```

I can't use `_dbContext.SimpleQM.FromSqlRaw();` this will throw an exception and telling that the model is not included in the Context.
how can I achieve same functionality in ef core 3.1?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problem solved!
just used this configuration.

```
builder.Entity<SimpleQueryModel>().HasNoKey().ToView("view_name_that_doesnt_exist");
```

Comment: Ugly, but works. Head slapper that they decided to not support this in an intelligent way.

Comment: @JamesHancock, not necessary ugly, that is similar way (if not exact) to groom a regular set. And this is according to https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14194 - citing: "We introduced "query types" in 2.1 as types that don't have a primary key defined. However, more and more it is looking that these should just be entity types without primary keys defined. This doesn't mean that they will behave differently, just that they will be represented by and called entity types."

Comment: BTW, it's pretty similar to how we treat views in database world. Views are sets, at the end of the day, can be joined and calculated in the same way, only the source definition is different a bit. Maybe not a bit, but.. only ;-)

Comment: Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#query-types-are-consolidated-with-entity-types