# The required column was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation :. FromSqlInterpolated

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, autorest, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

[Pre-Amble]

When I upgraded my api from .netcore2.1 to .netcore3.1 I found I needed to change my Entity Framework code considerably.

What I didn't realise was that I had a bug in a stored procedure in my remote database, that was not being expressed in my .netcore2.1 code.

The error messages I experienced did not point me in the direction of checking inside the stored procedure.  I leave the final form of my question in case searching for the error messages helps someone.

[Question]

I have the following code to call a stored procedure that returns an integer

The code works in a server side unit test but fails when it is called via the api or via SwaggerUI

```
var obj = connect.Ints.FromSqlInterpolated<intDto>(@$"Set NOCOUNT ON
          declare @num int 
          exec @num = spGetDefaultID {userName}  
          select @num as num").ToList();

id = (int)obj.First().num;
```

Where connect is my DbContext containing

```
public DbSet<intDto> Ints { get; set; }  // I actually don't want a table
```

with

```
public class intDto
{
    public int num { get; set; }
}
```

I followed [the advice to create a dummy view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427708/ef-core-3-dbquery-equivalent-functionality) so that I would not get an unwanted table in my database.

and have

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<intDto>).HasNoKey().ToView("view_name_that_doesnt_exist");
```

The call stack is

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The required column 'num' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.BufferedDataRecord.InitializeFields()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.BufferedDataRecord.Initialize(DbDataReader reader, IReadOnlyList`1 columns)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.BufferedDataReader.Initialize(IReadOnlyList`1 columns) 
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)   
at MyAPi.Job_Management.JobDataRead.GetCartIdForUser(ApiDbContext connect, String userName)
```

Note I have edited this question heavily because at one point I had the api working , but no longer do.

I found that I had to use .ToList() or I got an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: FromSqlRaw or FromSqlInterpolated
>   was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.
>   Consider calling `AsEnumerable` after the FromSqlRaw or
>   FromSqlInterpolated method to perform the composition on the client
>   side.

[Update]

I popped the following code in and it did not fail

```
 var obj = db.Ints.FromSqlInterpolated(@$"Set NOCOUNT on
                                       select count(*) as num from people 
                                       where email like  {name} ").ToList();
```

so next step is to try making a new stored procedure

Alternatively maybe it is the database version..

Interestingly the unit test fails unless I have

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
```

referenced in the project being tested. Even though I do not explicitly use that.

The error message in this scenario is

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found:'System.Linq.IQueriable '1<!!O> 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.
FromSqlInterpolated(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCOre.DbSet'1<!!0>, 
System.FormattableString)'
```

I tried changing my code to

```
var obj = connect.Ints.FromSqlInterpolated<intDto>(@$"declare @num int 
          exec @num = spGetDefaultID {userName}").ToList();
```

But my unit test gave an error

```
The underlying reader doesn't have as many fields as expected
```

[Update]

The remote stored procedure returns data using a result set.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetDefaultID] 
@email varchar(300)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare @cartID int
    select @CartID= id from people where email = @email   /* simplified */
    select @CartID /* this line was not present in my local database */
    return @CartID  
END
```

Comment: Public int? num.  ???

Comment: @ErikEJ Good thought but it does not work.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to run the sql code directly in SSMS?

Comment: @ZoharPeled you solved it. Care to write it up? When I ran the sp in SSMS I got 2 result sets. I put the sp code at the end of the question.

Comment: I didn't really solve anything, just pointed you to the right direction. I think you should post an answer to your own question.

Comment: @GertArnold The problem turned out to be in the stored procedure, as per my answer.  The error messages I received did not point me to that fact so I am thinking other people may still find this question useful ( i.e if you get the error then check your sp) . Should I edit it once more to add this as a pre-amble?

Comment: OK, I missed the latest revision + answer  because the question had been open for a while in a tab. Still, the question could be condensed considerably, making it and the answer more worth reading for future visitors.

Comment: One random thing to add, you can use the WITH RESULT SETS portion of EXEC to define the output columns & their names. Just solved my FromSql issue with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried calling the stored proc using ssms as suggested by Zohar, I was supprised to see 2 results output

When I removed the unnecessary

select @CartID

the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to modify your Stored Procedure. You need an OUTPUT Parameter. It should look sth. like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetDefaultID] (
                 @Username VARCHAR(100)
                ,@num_output int OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT @num_output = count(*)
  FROM [Person].[Person]
  WHERE PersonType LIKE (@Username)
RETURN
END
```

2.You need to modify one line of your code. The syntax is slightly different to the one you chose. You need the OUTPUT statement.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @num INT
exec spGetDefaultID {UserName}, @num_output=@num OUTPUT;
SELECT @num AS num
```

One of the confusing parts for you was probably that SQL is returning a value even if you write it like you did it at the beginning, but it is not storing the result in the @num Parameter.

I hope this is solving your issue.
More Information on how to how to [Return Data from a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) can be found on Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Thanks Mathias. I updated the question to show I am returning the data via a result set.