# DbQuery cannot be found - how to convert EF Core model to .NET 7.0?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I need to migrate a project from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 7.0 to host it as Azure web app.

I have encountered breaking changes in EF Core.

My model code:

```
public DbQuery<KonfiguraceZona> QZona { get; set; }
public DbQuery<KonfiguraceUzivatel> QKonfiguraceUzivatel { get; set; }
public DbQuery<KonfiguraceDepo> QKonfiguraceDepo { get; set; }

public DbQuery<StatusDepo> FStatusDepo { get; set; }
public DbQuery<StatusNakladac> FStatusNakladac { get; set; }
public DbQuery<StatusZona> FStatusZona { get; set; }
    
// ...

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Query<KonfiguraceZona>().ToView("QZona");
    modelBuilder.Query<KonfiguraceUzivatel>().ToView("QKonfiguraceUzivatel");
    modelBuilder.Query<KonfiguraceDepo>().ToView("QKonfiguraceDepo");
    modelBuilder.Query<AktivniRelaceUzivatele>();

    // Data being loaded using a parametrized SQL function
    Depos = db.FStatusDepo.FromSql("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FStatusDepo] ({0})", uzivatelId).ToList();
    Zonas = db.FStatusZona.FromSql("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FStatusZona] ({0})", uzivatelId).ToList();
    Nakladacs = db.FStatusNakladac.FromSql("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FStatusNakladac] ({0})", uzivatelId).ToList();
}
```

`DbQuery` and `Query` are no longer found in EF Core 7.

[EF Core 3 DbQuery equivalent functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59427708/2224701)

How to convert those types to EF 7?

Comment: Does not the linked question addresses the issue?

Comment: @GuruStron Not sure, perheps somehow, but at least I have not figured it out yet.

Comment: I have not used the `DbQuery`'s but the answer states that you just change them to `DbSet`s and set up as keyless entities with `ToView` mapping.

Comment: The [DbQuery class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbquery-1?view=efcore-3.1) says: `Use DbSet<T> instead` in a big red callout at the top of the page. Have you tried this? What did you try and what's the *actual* problem? Are you getting a compilation error?

Comment: Lots of things change in later asp .net versions. Even the code inside the Program.cs has changed where in built libraries are automatically added without use of the using statement

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is probably duplicate, but at least I can show, how I used this answer:

[EF Core 3 DbQuery equivalent functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59428468/2224701)

```
    public DbSet<StatusDepo> FStatusDepo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StatusNakladac> FStatusNakladac { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StatusZona> FStatusZona { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StatusUzivatel> FStatusUzivatel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VjezdPoLhute> FVjezdyPoLhute { get; set; }

    public DbSet<KonfiguraceZona> QZona { get; set; }
    public DbSet<KonfiguraceUzivatel> QKonfiguraceUzivatel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<KonfiguraceDepo> QKonfiguraceDepo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<KonfiguraceZona>().HasNoKey().ToView("QZona");
        modelBuilder.Entity<KonfiguraceUzivatel>().HasNoKey().ToView("QKonfiguraceUzivatel");
        modelBuilder.Entity<KonfiguraceDepo>().HasNoKey().ToView("QKonfiguraceDepo");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AktivniRelaceUzivatele>().HasNoKey();
        modelBuilder.Entity<StatusDepo>().HasNoKey();
        modelBuilder.Entity<StatusNakladac>().HasNoKey();
        modelBuilder.Entity<StatusZona>().HasNoKey();
        modelBuilder.Entity<StatusUzivatel>().HasNoKey();
        modelBuilder.Entity<VjezdPoLhute>().HasNoKey();

        // Data being loaded using a parametrized SQL function
        Depos = db.FStatusDepo.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FStatusDepo] ({0})", uzivatelId).ToList();
        Zonas = db.FStatusZona.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FStatusZona] ({0})", uzivatelId).ToList();
        Nakladacs = db.FStatusNakladac.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FStatusNakladac] ({0})", uzivatelId).ToList();
```